# Doxygen and undocumented items

Tags: doxygen

Recently I started using Doxygen and I feel it works as intended.
Now I need to focus a bit on undocumented items as the project - well you can guess it.

I'd like to create a separate page/group that lists undocumented items so it is easier to find them for users (a warning in the log gets ignored too easily). But even more I'd like to sort out low hanging fruits first. Let me explain...

When looking at code others wrote it is sometimes hard to guess what it does. Especially so if it calls other undocumented methods. It is much easier to understand methods that do not call other methods, or that only make use of documented methods.

So would it be possible for Doxygen to track the call stack and identify code that only depends on nothing or already documented code, and only add those items to the extra page? -- Ah, if the item in question is a structure or constant it can be treated as something not depending on undocumented stuff...

Edit:
Doxygen version is 1.9.5

I believe Doxygen understands the code well enough as in the logs I see messages such as

```
Generating caller graph for function ExtractChannel_4
```

My Doxyfile looks like

```
$ doxygen -x Doxyfile 
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'PROJECT_ICON' at line 59, file Doxyfile
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.1
PROJECT_NAME           = Project
PROJECT_LOGO           = icon.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./doxygen/
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       =
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
INPUT                  = Doc/ApiDocIntro.dox \
                         ./src
FILE_PATTERNS          =
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = NO
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
$
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Some ideas. Doxygen has no facility for following a call stack (It is not a compiler) it has to create a call and caller graph (see CALL_GRAPH and CALLER_GRAPH or REFERENCE_RELATIONS / REFERENCED_BY_RELATION) which shows a bit of the structure. (probably also best to set EXTRACT_ALL and other EXTRACT... settings so you get everything). Without the EXTRACT_ALL there is also a good chance that you get warnings about undocumented entities.

Comment: Would not knowledge about the call graph be sufficient for this decision? Just strip off the documented items and decide if the list is empty...

Comment: Note when you use `doxygen -x Doxyfile` you get all settings that differ from the default settings. I'm thinking about the other problem.

Comment: Maybe to give the undocumented functions in the call graph a different border color so they stand out a bit (I cannot test this at the moment also  the reason for some half comments that appeared). It is maybe a good idea to make an enhancement request in the doxygen issue tracker on github.

Comment: Note the current doxygen version is 1.9.8

Comment: I filed https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10396